# apply javascript function on a form generated by typo3

Tags: javascript, typo3

I am new to typo 3 . I created a log in form from the backend of typo3 and I want to apply some javascript input validation functions . I know how to attach a js file to the template (page) .

a simple example is ,I want to get the value of an input (getElementById selector ) , but when I see the generated html code  using firebug there is no id attribute to that input .

Any help ?

Comment: I don't know about adding an ID with Typo3 but with js you can select an input through other attributes. Example: document.querySelectorAll('input[name="first_name"]')[0]

Comment: You can try document.forms[0].name where name is the name attribute of the element you want to reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own HTML template for the login form. Assuming you use the login form that comes with TYPO3 and you are using TYPO3 6.2, you can do it this way:

- Copy the file `typo3/sysext/felogin/template.html` to some other place. Don't modify it directly, it would be overwritten by updates.
- Edit the copied file to your needs.
- Configure the login form to use the copied template. You can do that by either selecting the template in the settings of the login form in the backend, or by setting the TypoScript value `plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.template` to the path of the template.